# How Javascript handle long tasks such a timer countdown

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a Javascript code that runs a timer countdown that will update the counter per second in my database. I used AJAX to run my script, update my database and get the data(counter - seconds) from my database to echo it to my UI. However, once I refresh the page and/or go to another page in my website, the script stops and from counting down and it affects my database so mysql is not able to continue echoing the remaining time. What should I do?

````````html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" href="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
"></script>
<body>
<form method="post">
<div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="
  text-align: center;margin-bottom: 20px; z-index: 1;">
    <input type="number" id="time_hr" value="00" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" maxlength="2">
    :<input type="number" id="time_min" value="00" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" maxlength="2">
    :<input type="number" id="time_sec" value="00" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" maxlength="2">
    <input type="button" id="btn_Time" value="GO" onclick="startNa()">
  </div>
  <div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="row" style="z-index: 1;">
    <p id="time1" style="font-size: 50px; text-align: center;"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(getTimer1, 1000);

  });

    var ctr;
    var timerInterval;
    function timerKo() {

      var minShow = parseInt(ctr/60) < 10 ? "0"+ parseInt(ctr/60) :  parseInt(ctr/60);

      var hourShow = parseInt(ctr/3600) < 10 ? "0"+parseInt(ctr/3600) : parseInt(ctr/3600);

      var secShow = ctr%60 < 10 ? "0"+(ctr%60) : (ctr%60);
      // document.getElementById('time1').innerHTML = hourShow+":"+ minShow+":"+secShow;
      // document.getElementById("counter1").innerHTML = ctr;

      $.post('updateTimerTime.php',
        {
          'timer1_update':true,
          'seconds': ctr
        },function(data, status)
        {
          // alert(data);
        });
      ctr--;
      if(ctr == -1) {
        // <?php
        //  shell_exec - off
        // ?>```````
        alert("ZERO Na");
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
      }

    }
    function startNa() {
      var sec = parseInt(document.getElementById("time_sec").value);
      var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("time_min").value);
      var hour = parseInt(document.getElementById("time_hr").value);
      hour = hour * 60 * 60;
      min = min  * 60;
      sec = sec;
      ctr = hour + min + sec;
      timerInterval = window.setInterval(timerKo, 1000);

    }

    function getTimer1()
    {
      $.post('getTimerTime.php',
      {
          'getTimer1': true
      }, function(data, status){
        $("#time1").html(data);
      });
    }
  </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    require 'conn.php';
    if(isset($_POST['timer1_update']))
    {
        // echo "TIIMER ";
        $seconds = $_POST['seconds'];
        $sql = "UPDATE timers SET timerswitch='$seconds' WHERE id=1";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    }

?>

<?php
    require 'conn.php';
    if (isset($_POST['getTimer1'])) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM timers WHERE id=1";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $time_1 = $data['timerswitch'];
        $sec_1 = intval($time_1%60) < 10 ? 0 . intval($time_1%60) : intval($time_1%60);
        $min_1 = intval(($time_1/60)%60) < 10 ? 0 . intval(($time_1/60)%60) : (($time_1/60)%60);
        $hr_1 = intval($time_1/3600) < 10 ? 0 . intval($time_1/3600) : intval($time_1/3600);
        echo $hr_1 . ":" . $min_1 . ":" . $sec_1;

    }
?>
````````

Comment: Don't insert values continuously to the database. insert start time to the database and whenever you want to display remaining, use that inserted start time.

Comment: You can't force people to stay on that page, using a client side timer is not a good idea.

Comment: *"once I refresh the page and/or go to another page in my website, the script stops"* If you store the count down in `javascript` (client-side) once you navigate to a new page or refresh/reload your `javascript` will also lose the previous values and execute like it would for the first time. If you try to update your database on a loop you will be spamming your own website with requests and possibly cause a self DDOS. As suggested above, store the start time and when reloading/navigating use that time and current time to start the counter.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just to clarify, I can use javascript to insert my start time into my database and use PHP to countdown on my UI?

Comment: Use Javascript to pass your start time and save it to database using PHP. When you display your timer, use Javascript.